# Explanation of the synthesize statement in terms of delegates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, synthesize

I have the following code in the interface file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
@class FaxRecipient;

//Definition of the delegate's interface
@protocol AddLocalRecipientsTableViewControllerDelegate
-(void)getLocalRecipient:(FaxRecipient*)recipient;
@end

@interface AddLocalRecipientsTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *localRecipientItems;
    NSURLConnection *connectionInprogress;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath;
    FaxRecipient * faxRecipient;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath;
@property(nonatomic,retain)FaxRecipient * faxRecipient;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<AddLocalRecipientsTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;


-(void) loadLocalRecipients;
```

I have the following line in my implementation file:

```
@synthesize delegate=_delegate;
```

What does the synthesize with the underscore mean? I mean I know what a regular synthesize does. Everything works OK and I looked at this code example at some other site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of many. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=objc+property+underscore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does @synthesize window=_window do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170631/what-does-synthesize-window-window-do)

Answer (score 0):

Your properties almost always have a backing variable. What

```
@synthesize delegate=_delegate;
```

does is declare that the backing variable for your search bar will be called _searchBar. This allows you to decouple the name of the property from the name of your variable. In fact, if you don't use @synthesize you don't need to have a backing variable at all.

This can:

1. avoid clashes with variable names
   and
2. make it clear when I'm using a
   local variable and when I'm using an
   instance variable.