# What's the point of @syntheisze abc = _abc;?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does @synthesize window=_window do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170631/what-does-synthesize-window-window-do)
>   [Question about @synthesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112283/question-about-synthesize)

Some developers tend to use this convention:

```
@syntheisze abc = _abc;
```

What is the true benefit of this? Why do they do it this way? The first thing I notice is that it makes the code a lot harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common code convention:

See this Google Objective-C coding directives: 
http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml?showone=Properties#Properties

Comment: Google's convention is that class member variables have trailing underscores: abc_, not _abc.