# Beginner Objective C syntax observation

Tags: objective-c, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does @synthesize window=_window do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170631/what-does-synthesize-window-window-do)

How come when you `@synthesize` something like `buttonPressed` , You need to do this:

```
@synthesize buttonPressed = buttonPressed_;
```

I've been following some tutorials and this keeps coming up. Why?

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to do it that way.

By default, `@synthesize variableName` does work, if your synthesized accessors shall have the same name as your instance variable.

In your example, the instance variable is called `buttonPressed_` but your accessor methods will omit the `_` and thus just be called `setButtonPressed` and `buttonPressed`.