# In Objective-C, what does the code after an @synthesize mean?

Tags: objective-c, synthesize

Sorry for the bad title, I wasn't sure what else to call this question.  Anyways, suppose I have the following:

```
@synthesize display = _display
```

My question is what is the difference between display and _display?  What does each refer to?

To clarify, I know what @synthesize does (it creates getters and setters) but I'm not sure exactly what the difference what display and _display refer to.

I'm proficient at java, so whenever possible relate your answer to it.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does @synthesize window=_window do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170631/what-does-synthesize-window-window-do)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`display` is the name of the property. It also affects what the getters and setters will be called.

`_display` is the underlying field in the object which the property will access. Some people like to leave it the same as the property -- this behavior occurs by default, so it's easy; some people like to prefix their fields with underscores. (Some crazy people also like to use completely different names, but they're crazy.)

Comment: I prefer your answer to the documentation-quotation answer just because you have rightfully recognized a certain group of people as crazy.

Comment: lately i've taken to not declaring the field at all.  "@property" and "@synthesize" will also declare the field for you if you omit it, thus (IMHO) making the code even cleaner.

Comment: Ok, I guess the logical next question is what is the difference between a property and this underlying field?  Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to Objective-C; I just need a simple answer.  It just seems that both properties and this "underlying field" are very similar to instance variables in java

Comment: Fields are instance variables. Properties are a shorthand syntax for invoking accessor functions, as well as a way of automatically generating those accessors.

Comment: The "underlying field" is exactly an instance variable. Declaring a property is telling the compiler that you want to be allowed to access a certain value from the object using dot notation as opposed to getter/setter methods (although you can always use those too- they are equivalent). Adding @synthesize to the mix gets you implementations of the accessors for free, including correct memory management based on the property declaration (e.g. retain, assign, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

From [Declared Properties - Property Implementation Directives](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW9):

> You can use the form `property=ivar` to indicate that a particular instance variable should be used for the property, for example:

```
@synthesize firstName, lastName, age=yearsOld;
```

> This specifies that the accessor methods for `firstName`, `lastName`, and `age` should be synthesized and that the property `age` is represented by the instance variable `yearsOld`.

Answer (score 0):

this is saying that the display getter and setter provide access to the _display member variable.

you can use this to rename your properties externally.