# Difference between _ and self. in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, getter-setter, synthesize

Is there a difference between using the underscore and using the `self` keyword in Objective-C when calling an `@property`?

Property declaration:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *myString;
```

Calling `@synthesize` on the property:

```
@synthesize myString = _myString;
```

Is there a difference if I want to use it in my code? When? In the getter/setter?

```
self.myString = @"test";
_myString = @"test";
```

Comment: `self` is a symbol.  `_` is a character in some symbols.  `myString` and `_myString` are two different symbols that happen to be related, not because of spelling but because they're named in the same `@synthezize`.

Comment: Try the following answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170631/what-does-synthesize-window-window-do

Comment: Check if @Jonathan's answer to this previous SO question helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466496/why-rename-synthesized-properties-in-ios-with-leading-underscores

Comment: as per my knowledge it is same

Comment: @AalokParikh -- If you think they're the same, try `[instancePtr set_myString:@"ABC"]`

Comment: ok from the above questions given as links i got the knowledge about it both are deferent in nature sorry for my comment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466496/why-rename-synthesized-properties-in-ios-with-leading-underscores <- This is great, Thanks @7KV7! Now this is clear for me.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`self.myString = @"test";` is exactly equivalent to writing `[self setMyString:@"test"];`. Both of these are calling a method.

You could have written that method yourself. It might look something like this:

```
- (void)setMyString:(NSString*)newString
{
    _myString = newString;
}
```

Because you used `@synthesize`, you don't have to actually bother writing that method, you can just allow the compiler to write it for you.

So, from looking at that method, it looks like calling it will do the exact same thing as just assigning a value to the instance variable, right? Well, it's not so simple.

Firstly, you could write your own setter method. If you do so, your method would get called, and it could do all sorts of additional things as well as setting the variable. In that case, using `self.myString =` would call your method, but doing `_myString =` would not, and thus different functionality would be used.

Secondly, if you ever use Key Value Observing, the compiler does some very clever tricks. Behind the scenes, it subclasses your class, and overrides your setter method (whether it's one you wrote yourself or one generated by synthesize), in order to make the calls to `willChangeValueForKey:` that are needed for Key Value Observing to work. You don't need to know how this works (although it's quite interesting if you want some bedtime reading!), but you do need to know that if you want Key Value Observing to work automatically, you have to use setter methods.

Thirdly, calling the setter method even if you're relying on synthesize to write one gives you flexibility for the future. You might want to do something extra whenever a value is changed, and at the point you discover you want to do that, you can manually write a setter method — if you're in the habit of always using `self.myString =`, then you won't need to change the rest of your code to start calling the new method!

Fourthly, the same applies to subclasses. If someone else was to subclass your code, if you use the setters then they could override them to adjust the functionality.

Any time you access the instance variable directly, you're explicitly not providing a way for extra functionality to be hooked in at that point. Since you or someone else might want to hook in such functionality in the future, it pays to use the setters all the time, unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: Note that I didn't mention the memory management implications. If you're using ARC, they're a lot less relevant in this case, so I skipped over them.

Comment: By the way, regarding the first sentence... This is true 99% of the time, but if you have a custom setter (specified with `setter=` in the property declaration), then the two forms are not exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 9):

You are correct - the first version (`self.myString`) calls the synthesized getter/setter and the second version access the private member variable directly.

It looks like you are using ARC, so in that case it doesn't make that much of a difference.  However, if you aren't using ARC, it can make a difference as assigning to the private member directly won't trigger the automatic retain/release or copy/release logic that is generated for you by using `synthesize`.

Comment: They're two different symbols. One could be "aardvark" and the other "zebra" and still have the variable-setter/getter relationship.

Comment: @Hot Licks - You are correct that the names are irrelevant, but as I read the question, I think he was wondering what the practical difference is between using the synthesized property vs. just using the member variable backing it.

Comment: @EricPetroelje - yes, that exactly what I asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `_` (underscore) is simply a convention, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466601/248062).

When you don't prefix a property access with `self.`, you are accessing the underlying variable directly, as in a c `struct`. In general, you should only ever do this in your init methods and in custom property accessors. This allows stuff like computed properties and [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html%20KVC) to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tip not mentionend,  the access using underscore is faster and the access using self is safer (KVC). Maybe this can summarise when you have to use each one.