# How to save text from textview?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextview

I have a textview where you can write multiple lines of text. How do you save that text in a file or variables?

I used the multiline text field but it doesn't let me go to next line unless I hit control enter.

What I'm thinking is like a text editor, after you type everything you save that in a file. Or I can get each line from the text view into a variable.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I haven't set up code because I don't know what to use. Can you get text from a textview? Or do I have to set up a textfield. Right now I just have a text view in a viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSString` can save text up to 4.2 billion characters. `\n` denotes a line break, so no need to save into multiple parameters.

```
NSString *text = textView.text;
```

OSX

```
NString *text = [[textView textStorage] string];
```

If you're looking for each individual line for whatever reason, you could use `componentsSeparatedByString`

```
NSArray *linesArray = [textView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Each line will be available at `linesArray[0]`, `linesArray[1]` etc...
`[linesArray count]` will give you the total number of lines... with `linesArray[[linesArray count]-1]` being the last line in the string.

The `textView.text` property is an `NSString` also... so when you say saved.. do you mean intra app session? If so you can use `NSUserDefaults`

Save object

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:textView.text forKey:@"TheKeyForMyText"];
```

Get object

```
NSString *text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"TheKeyForMyText"];
```

Comment: NSString *example;
    example = _inputText.text;

Comment: Thats what i have to save the text but it says text is not a property of the text view.

Comment: And _inputText is `@property (nonatomic) UITextView *inputText;`?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use `_inputText` but `self.inputText` if it's set up as above

Comment: its NSTextView. should it be UITextView.

Comment: NSTextView you need `stringValue` or `[[myTextView textStorage] string]`

Comment: got it thanks!! Can you just explain the difference between self.text view and _textview?

Comment: `self.` is pointing to a property... otherwise you're going for the variable directly, which you may not be able to do without custom getting and setting.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333495/difference-between-and-self-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

Assign
In swift

```
let var_name = textfield.text
```

Or in objective C

```
NSString *string_name = textfield.text;
```

And use the variable where you want to.