# How to access property declared in interface from implementation file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject
     @property(strong,nonatomic)  NSString *firstName;   
@end
```

Comment: can you elaborate it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access "firstName" in Person.m then simply you can use

> self.firstName

And If you want to access it in any other controller then you will have to create object of **Person** Class and then only you can read or write it's properties.
e.g.

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
person.firstName = @"Xyz";
NSLog(@"name is->%@", person.firstName);
```

Comment: what about `@synthesize` and  `_`  for same class ?

Comment: self.variable will retain an object for you if you mark the property with retain or strong.  _ variable does not address memory management at all..

This is well descibed here.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10333755/5172413