# Objective C, what are the primary gains of accessing the properties via the underscore _

Tags: objective-c

I've taken over an iOS objective C code base where the code predominantly uses the underscore _ to access properties within the class bypassing the self.myVariable .  I'm not sure why the previous programmer did this.  It seems to defeat the purpose of properties.

Besides bypassing a getter if one exists, what are the primary gains of accessing the properties via the underscore _ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333495/difference-between-and-self-in-objective-c have a look at this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \_ and self. in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333495/difference-between-and-self-in-objective-c)

Comment: lot of explanation you can find for this by a single [google search](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=difference+between+_+and+self+in+ios&*).

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to access a property directly via the underscore is to bypass the getter/setter. Functionally there generally won't be a huge difference in the majority of cases, but there are a number of advantages to accessing properties via the setters/getters (i.e. self), including:

- Key Value Observing - if you do want to observe when a property value is changed, it'll only be possible if it's done via a setter (including default setter).
- Versatility in the future - If you primarily access a property via self, you then have the option of creating a getter/setter down the track without having to change all your references to the property.

Bottom line, accessing and setting a property directly (via _) simply limits your options for no gain.

**Edit:** As Willeke has pointed out, accessing a property directly is technically faster than doing so via an accessor (via self). For the most part this difference is negligible, but there are feasibly scenarios where it's relevant.

Comment: Accessing the ivar is faster.

Comment: Extremely marginally, though I guess there are potentially scenarios where you need to access a property multiple times and don't need the accessors.  Still rather trivial compared to the potential advantages from using accessors, but I'll update my answer regardless.

Comment: Also if one needs to get at the actual bits, to get the address one must use the underscore.